# c++ - constructor cannot be used to intitialize

Tags: c++, class

I have a problem and I would be happy to help.

i have a class player:

```
class Player{

public: 

char Name[20];
Dice* dice;
int points; 

Player(char name[20], Dice* dice){//constructor
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        Name[i] = name[i];
    points = 0;
}
```

and in my main i try:

```
    Player* p1("aaa",d1);
    Player* p2("ddd",d2);
```

the error:

```
error a value of type const char * cannot be used to initialize an entity of 
type "Player*"
```

It's just part of the code but all the rest of the code is fine except for this one.

thank's.

Comment: You want `Player p1("aaa",d1);` or `Player* p1 = new Player("aaa",d1);`; depends on what you want `p1` to be.

Comment: `Player* p1` is creating a `Player` *pointer*, not a `Player` instance. Perhaps you wanted `Player* p1(new Player("aaa", d1))` or `Player p1("aaa", d1)`?

Comment: Can you please explain to me the difference

Comment: Better to have `std::string name;`.

Comment: @david If you have no special reason for using a raw pointer, then go with `Player p1("aaa",d1);`.

Comment: i try Player* p1(new Player("aaa", d1)) but i get this error>>> no instance of constructor matches the argument list argument type are :(const char[4],Dice())

Comment: @songyuanyao i try Player p1("aaa",d1); but still error

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn what pointers are.

Comment: @david `"aaa"` is `const char[4]`, which can't be converted to `char*` implicitly. Change the type of parameter `name` to `const char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new` to construct an object dynamically and assign to a pointer:

```
Player *p1 = new Player("aaa", d1);
```

You should also change the constructor to take `const char name[]`. Otherwise, you can't use a string literal as the argument.

And the loop that copies from `name` to `Name` needs to check for a null byte, otherwise you'll read past the end of `"aaa"`.

```
Player(const char name[], Dice* dice){//constructor
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Name); i++) {
        Name[i] = name[i];
        if (name[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    points = 0;
}
```

It would probably be better if you used `std::string` instead of a fixed-length `char` array.

=== Example added by phonetagger... ===
(I was working on an answer when Barmar posted this answer.)

```
#include <string>

class Player
{

public:
   std::string Name;
   Dice* dice;
   int points;

   //constructor
   Player(std::string name, Dice* dice)
      : Name(name), dice(dice), points(0)
   {
   }
};

int main()
{
   Dice *d1 = new Dice();

   Player* p1 = new Player("aaa", d1);
   Player* p2 = new Player("ddd", d1);
}
```

Comment: thank's You really helped me.     now when i try in class :Game(Player* p1, Player* p2)  i get unddefind >>>> in my main: Game g1(*p1,*p2);    sorry my mistake P >>> p this is the problem

Comment: It should be `Game g1(p1, p2)`

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: fixit
`Player* p1` is jus a pointer to a `Player` object, you need to point to an object:

```
Player playerP1("aaa",d1);

Player* p1(&playerP1);
```

So you have an object `playerP1`, pointed by `p1`

Idem for `p2`;

---

Step 2: go pro
You can also asign to a pointer dynamicaly using `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared`:

```
auto p1 = std::make_shared<Player>("aaa",d1);
```

So you use the benefits of smart pointers and avoid using `new`, and naked new( which is not recommended nowadays anymore).

Comment: i change the cosntruct to Player(const char name[20], Dice* dice) and in main Player playerP1("aaa",d1); but still red line under "aaa"

Comment: @david, as you see in other answer and comments, you have two alternatives to solve this new issue: "Change the type of parameter name to `const char*`" or use `std::string`

Answer (score -2):

Change your constructor to

```
Player(const char *name, Dice* dice)
```